# Combinatorial designs give triangulations of complete graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, combinatorial-designs

I recently attended a talk on combinatorial design theory. The speaker mentioned briefly that the Fano plane, and other designs give rise to triangulations of complete graphs (the Fano plane gives a triangulation of $K_7$). I'm interested in graph embeddings, and I wonder if anyone has any good references on the connections between design theory and graph embeddings? The speaker didn't, nor did my adviser, so I'm putting my faith on the internet. I've figured out that one would need two designs that are somehow connected to obtain an embedding. Is there anyone here who knows more about this?

Comment: See S.R Alpert: Two-fold triple systems and graph imbeddings
J. Combin. Theory, 18 (1975), pp. 101–107 for a start.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thank you!